# GWT ButtonCell Changing Text

Tags: gwt

How can I change ButtonCell text that's embedded in celltable column when button pressed.
I've onnly seen setFieldUpdater.
Also is there some easy way to update another CellTable column rather then accessing it directly

Answer (score 2):

Cell widgets are "model-based" (MVP), you have to update the object rendered in the row (the one passed to the FieldUpdater) and then tell the CellTable that the value changed and it should redraw (use setRowData, using the index passed to the FieldUpdater).
Something like:

```
new FieldUpdater<MyObject, String>() {
  @Override
  public void update(int index, MyObject object, String value) {
    object.setSomeField("foo");
    cellTable.setRowData(index, Collections.singletonList(object));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. originally I cretaed cellTable.redraw(); but that updates whole table. What' the purose of Collections.singletonList(object)?
To pass more then one object to cell?

Comment: `setRowData` expects a `List`, but you only have a single object; `java.util.Collections.singletonList` builds a `List` around your single object; it's easier than creating a new, say, `ArrayList` to add your object to it. BTW, `setRowData` *updates* the items (rows) starting at `index`; passing a singleton list only updates the `index` row; passing a list with two items would update both `index` and `index+1` rows.

Comment: Hi Thomas, logging the render method on a custom cell seems that the table is rendering twice when updating a single object with FieldUpdater. Any thought? http://pastebin.com/xxeqXSXw